# Python schedule jobs doesn't start

Tags: python, schedule

Why the work is not being performed? If you remove `schedule.clear()` everything works, but the scripts are duplicated.

```
def greet(name):
    print('Hello', name)

while True: 
    schedule.clear()
    with open("config.json") as config:
        data = json.load(config)
        if data["start"]:
            date = data["time"]          
            for i in date:
                schedule.every().day.at(i).do(greet, name =data["name"])  
            config.close()
            all_jobs = schedule.get_jobs()
            print(all_jobs)
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

output

```
[Every 1 day at 09:18:00 do greet(name='Лариса') (last run: [never], next run: 2021-06-26 09:18:00), Every 1 day at 09:19:00 do greet(name='Лариса') (last run: [never], next run: 2021-06-25 09:19:00), Every 1 day at 09:20:00 do greet(name='Лариса') (last run: [never], next run: 2021-06-25 09:20:00)]
[Every 1 day at 09:18:00 do greet(name='Лариса') (last run: [never], next run: 2021-06-26 09:18:00), Every 1 day at 09:19:00 do greet(name='Лариса') (last run: [never], next run: 2021-06-26 09:19:00), Every 1 day at 09:20:00 do greet(name='Лариса') (last run: [never], next run: 2021-06-25 09:20:00)]
```

Comment: if your are working on linux you need to use `crontab` and schedule the job on the script and it will run everytime

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option.

Comment: if you are on windows you can use `task scheduler`

Comment: I work under linux. according to the customer's requirements, i am can not use cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your help. I found this solution

```
while True:
        with open("config.json") as config:
            data = json.load(config)
            if data["start"]:
                date = data["time"]
                now = datetime.datetime.now() 
                now = now.strftime('%H:%M')
                for i in date:
                    if i == now:
                        great(data["name"])
            time.sleep(1)
```